# Recording raw video format in android

Tags: android

I am totally new to android. Is it possible to record raw video format from the camera in android. 
Basically I have pandaboard running with ICS, i have USB camera(iball) connected. Now I want to record raw video formats from the USB camera. The camera supports raw video formats I have tested it by recording raw video formats on debian using ffmpeg.

In simple words output from the camera should be in yuv format

Comment: No one has come across the problem yet. ?

Comment: I'm currently facing the problem. For my master thesis I'd like to do something computer vision related. I want to record a raw video to have a reproducible test set, but compression artifacts interfere with the algorithms. Have you had any success so far?

Comment: NO I am not currently working on that :(

Comment: Ok, then I'll have a look myself and let you know if I manage to record uncomressed videos somehow.

Comment: @Mene I think in the lattest android version(kit kat) you might be having very good support to record uncompressed video. I am not very sure though, you can look at it.

Comment: I was able to record the preview image of the camera. Directly recording it is not supported though. It's pretty straight forward, you'll receive the data as a `byte[]`. The only problem is the bandwidth: the internal storage is way to slow. I solved this using deflate compression, AP-Mode on my laptop and tcp over usb (using adb forward).