# Record RAW video from Project Tango

Tags: android, google-project-tango

Anyone can help me to record RAW video from Project Tango?
I find the function called TangoImageBuffer to get Image data buffer but don't know clearly how to create an app to record the video( or set of Raw image sequence)

Comment: Which device are you using? The (now discontinued) Tango Developer Tablet or the Lenovo phone?

Comment: tango developper tablet

Comment: Comments in this question point to a possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18480830/recording-raw-video-format-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Tango device occupies the control of camera. When Tango is connected, the only data you will received regarding color camera would be the callback for onImageAvailable. It returns data in YUV format, and you have to do the conversion to make it into RAW format.

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c/blob/master/cpp_basic_examples/hello_video/src/main/jni/hello_video_app.cc#L33-L46) is a sample code of how to convert YUV into RGB on Tango.